# How to initialise and setup databases in MySQL 5.1.73 in Ubuntu after install it from source code?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

In order to work on Ruby 1.9.3/Rails 3.2.2 application, I have installed MySQL 5.1 in my Ubuntu machine using ([this script](https://gist.github.com/shichao-an/f5639ecd551496ac2d70)). But after that, I'm unable to login to console or doing any operation.

How can I get username and password or list databases and querying?

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I get username and password?

The default user is `root`, no password.

> If you have never assigned a root password for MySQL, the server does not require a password at all for connecting as root. However, this is insecure. For instructions on assigning a password, see [Section 2.10.4, “Securing the Initial MySQL Accounts”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/default-privileges.html).

Source [How to Reset the Root Password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking the script that you are using, the code belows in the script that says

```
mysqld_safe -user=mysql &
/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

should start mysqld server as the user(mysql) "AND" should execute the `mysql_secure_installation` script which will help you step through the following:

- Reset mysql root password
- Remove anonymous user
- Disable remote access to mysql
- Reload privilege tables.
- etc . .

And as what [DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill) said above there is no default root password, so when it ask you to enter the default root password just hit "Enter".